# Nhibernate .SaveOrUpdate, how to get if row was update or not, means RowCount

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I am updating a column in a SQL table and I want to check if it was updated successfully or it was updated already and my query didn't do anything
as we get `@@rowcount` in SQL Server.

In my case, I want to update a column named `lockForProcessing`, so if it is already processing, then my query would not affect any row, it means someone else is already processing it, else I would process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is related to a multi threading / concurrency problem, where the same table may be updated simultaneously.

You may want to have a look at the :
[Chapter 11. Transactions And Concurrency](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html)

- The ISession is not threadsafe!
- The entity is not stored the moment the code *session.SaveOrUpdate()* is executed, but *typically* after transaction.Commit().
- *stored* and *commited* are two different things.

  - The entity is *stored* after any session.Flush(). Depending on the IsolationLevel, the entity won't be seen by other transactions.
  - The entity is *commited* after a transaction.Commit(). A commit also flushes.

Maybe all you need to do is choose the right IsolationLevel when beginning transactions and then read the table row to get the current value:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            session.Get(); // Read your row
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

Maybe it is easier to create some locking or pipeline mechanism in your application code though. Without knowing more about who is accessing the database (other transactions, sessions, processes?) it is hard to answer more precisely.